# Unable to parse query string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to use this function, however, it's not working and giving me the error

> "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A"

I'd appreciate any help!

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGAiiV_vJba_VnCnJAwHHtZAL_GW_SbsHzKYAMRB3w0/edit#gid=614551224", "Sokkary!A:K"),"Select A,B,D,E,I,J,K where B >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("03/04/2024"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Col#` notation:

```cpp
"A,B,D,E,I,J,K" becomes "Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10,Col11"
```

So the final formula becomes:

```cpp
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGAiiV_vJba_VnCnJAwHHtZAL_GW_SbsHzKYAMRB3w0/edit#gid=614551224", "Sokkary!A:K"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10,Col11 where Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("03/04/2024"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```